# How to get the up time report for a Java Web Application deployed on Apache Tomcat 7?

Tags: java

How to get the up time report for a Java Web Application deployed on Apache Tomcat 7? By Up time I mean we have to show that Application is up and running.
Is there any tomcat log by which we can show?

Comment: I dont know about log but you can look for manager GUI

Answer (score 2):

Inside your contextDestroyed:

```
System.err.println(" -- uptime was : -- " +
    org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationISO(
        java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime()
    )
);
```

In millis:

> > ' -- uptime was : -- P0Y0M1D3H4M22.029S'
> >     Saying that, uptime was, 1 day 3 hours 4 minutes and 22 seconds briefly.

Hows that?

Comment: Ok, my bad, you can just do, netstat -tnlp | grep $TOMCAT_PORT && ps -eaf | grep $tomcat_path, anyway you like

Comment: To explain `netstat -tnlp | grep $TOMCAT_PORT && ps -eaf | grep $tomcat_path`: 
The first part will show you whether tomcat is running, the second will output something like `root      2061     1  0 21:00 ... or root      4856     1  0 Jan30 ...` depending on whether you have been up since 9 PM or January 30.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Tomcat generates the tomcat logs.
Check under $TOMCAT_PATH\logs folder.